# Android - draw image and texts on canvas in different positions

Tags: android, image, canvas, draw

I want to draw some texts and an image on canvas, [The template would be something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLtsB.png)

I managed to draw the texts, but I'm stuck on drawing the image.

Here is what I have done

```js
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(949, 300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

        TextPaint tp = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        tp.setColor(0xFF000000);
        tp.setTextSize(15 * getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
        tp.setShadowLayer(2, 0.5f, 0.5f, Color.BLACK);
        StaticLayout sl = new StaticLayout("This is",
                tp, 300, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1f, 0f, false);
        StaticLayout sm = new StaticLayout("This is",
                tp, 300, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1f, 0f, false);


        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(50, 20); //position text on the canvas
        sl.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(50, 90); //position text on the canvas
        sm.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

```html
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border_ui" />
```

Any idea how to draw the image?

Comment: Why not use 4 different components: a RelativeLayout as a card, two TextView and an ImageView. Would be far easier

Comment: because I am planning to export the image and save it after I draw all what I need to draw @Eselfar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
iv.draw(canvas); // Pass canvas to view to draw
```